# Is comparing Islamic things with someone or something in poetry haram?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

Is it sin to compare holy/Islamic things with someone or something in poetry?

A new Bollywood song is released in which he compared the streets of his lover with [Madina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medina) and [Mandir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandir) (Hindus worship place). Is it haram/sin to listen these sort of songs or what? Some people says that they are poets are they do these things in deep love but I think it is sin. Isn't it?

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can answer this?

Comment: Why do you think that Bollywood should be having an Islamic understanding, in the first place? In your opinion, how are the songs/albums they do, that are far from resemblance with Islamic terminology or Muslim culture, good and halal to listen to, that you single out a few songs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the mind of Poet. If by Madina you mean actually Madina, that your street is like Madina Or it has the value of Madina then this is a sin. If you use it symbolically then it may not matter in some cases. For example, By comparing the street with Madina, you mean to express the value of your love then it is okay. If you are a poet, you may understand symbolic use.